# Ratio of prime divisors to composite divisors

Tags: number-theory

What is the name for the function that gives the ratio of prime divisors to composite divisors of a given integer? Example, 5 gives (1,5:-) 2/0 = nan, 6 is (1,3:2,6) 2/2=1, 8 is (1:2,4,8) 1/3.  Has anyone ever analysed this sort of thing before? Is there somewhete I can read up on it?

Comment: Why are you treating $1$ as a prime?  As $2$ as not a prime?

Comment: And of course there would be the question of 1 not counting as a prime. In my example perhaps I would have been better to call it composite divisors and other? And to pay attention to where I put that two? Its one in the morning here, that was human error

Comment: I do not know of a name. Prime to overall is nicer, and *average* behaviour might be interesting.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217411/number-of-distinct-prime-divisors-of-an-integer-n-is-o-log-n-log-log-n I will have a look at this quesrion to see if therebisnsome insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy–Ramanujan_theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Ramanujan_theorem). Bingo, I do believe this is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: After some delay you can accept this answer so it doesn't show up unanswered.  I fixed the link.  If you click the link icon when posting the answer the site will put square brackets around the whole link and not get confused by the hyphen.

Comment: $\omega(n)$ has a normal order, but the divisor function ($d(n)$ or $\tau(n)$) doesn't have a normal order for the following reason.  By the Erdős-Kac theorem, there is a positive density of integers with $\omega(n) > \log\log n + \sqrt{\log \log n}$, and $\tau(n) \ge 2^{\omega(n)}$.  Conversely there is also a positive density of integers with $\Omega(n) < \log\log n - \sqrt{\log \log n}$, and $\tau(n) \le 2^{\Omega(n)}$.  So $\tau(n)$ often deviates significantly far on each side of $2^{\log\log n}$.